# Wordpress Images issue

Tags: wordpress

I have get some images issue. Images are not displayed even images are at the proper location. Also When I tried to open images in browser, it says *not found*. Wordpress version 4.8.3 with visual composer. Tried to upload images using wp - media. Images uploaded but does not work (displayed)

Steps followed to resolve is issue:

1. Give 777 permission to uploads directory and all subdirectory
   folders.
2. Inform host regarding the issue. but not able to solve the issue.
3. Check images by calling third site url. in that case images displayed.

Comment: You should include the code you're using to display the images.

Comment: Default wordpress functionality. 
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/image.png">

Comment: Hardcoding image urls it's not *default wordpress functionality* (see [Images](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/media/images/)), but if you're using this code, your issue may be related to the base path. Is your WP installed in the root of your domain?

Comment: Yes, Its installed on the root of the domain.
if this is case, Why is not display media images too. Media images are uploaded by default wordpress functionality from wp admin > media > library.

Comment: I'd use browser's devtools network tab to check the whole URL requested for this image and the response code received.

Comment: Yes, I use full path http://www/abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/image.png